# color plot depending on other value in libreoffice

Tags: scatter-plot, libreoffice-calc

I'm struggling with a very simple problem.

That's a very very small example of the DB:

```
A   B   C
10  40  1
13  45  1
15  43  0
11  38  1
10  47  0
```

What I'd like to do in Libreoffice Calc is to make a scatter plot A vs B, but I also want to color the single points according to the column C (example green if 1 and red if 0).

I've tried to play with `Data Ranges` or to select all the 3 columns together but it didn't worked.

I now it is a very simple issue to solve in R, but is it possible to do the same thing in LibreOffice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "helper column" as workaround. Starting with your example data, you could add a column `D` holding the `B` values only if `C=1`:

[image]

For example, D2 has the formula `=IF(C2;B2;"")`

Now, you can add a chart using columns `A`, `B` and `D`. Editing the data series properties of `D` and setting the line to `none` will just leave the icons on the chart. Since it's the "last" data series defined, it will cover the icons of `B`. Now, if you set the `D` icon shape to the same shape as `B`'s icons, you have a chart with the line of data series `B` and different icon colour if `C=1`:

[image]

AFAIK, you can't select different colors for the line and the icons of a data series, so you can't set the icon color of data series `B` to a different value than the line's color. If you need different colors here, you may use the same workaround for column `B`, adding a identical column and setting the line to `none`:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, Gnumeric allows for setting different line/icon colors, so implementing this whith Gnumeric may be easier than using OOO Calc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in gnumeric, you can use the so called XYcolor plot which colors the markers using the third column.